# Connection establishment b/w logicapps and apim

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management

Trying to connect logicapp and apim with integration account . In configuration setting it shows disabled and trying to enable and copy the ID but I can't

But unable to find and configuration for establishment it shows disable.

Please help me how to enable

Answer (score 1):

After reproducing from my end, I faced the same issue when the logic app and Integration Account and Logic App are in different regions.

Make sure you have your integration in the same region as your logic app and then you can add your integration account from workspace settings as shown in the below image.

[image]